# When applying the adiabatic theorem, why doesn't the gap become doubly exponentially small generically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-computer, adiabatic

Suppose we have a parameterised family of Hamiltonians $H(s)$, $s\in [0,1]$, acting on $n$ spins/qubits. When applying the adiabatic theorem, it is well known that if we wish to remain in the ground state with high probability as we move from $s=0$ to $s=1$, we need to perturb over a time scale scaling as $\sim 1/\Delta^2_{min}$, where $\Delta_{min}$ is the minimum spectral gap along the path $s\in [0,1]$.

I have often seen it stated that in the worst-case, $\Delta_{min} = 1/\exp(n)$. However, I can't find any reference for this being the worst-case. Why isn't it possible that $\Delta_{min} = 1/\exp(2^n)$, and hence we would need a doubly-exponentially long time to remain in the ground state?

I can't find any generic bounds on the eigenvalue gaps for Hamiltonians, so I can't necessarily see why a doubly-exponentially small gap should not be possible.

Some references regarding the gap when the adiabatic theorem is used to solve computational problems:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0206003 , the authors seem to think that an exponential runtime of the adiabatic algorithm is the worst case*.
- https://tjoresearchnotes.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/matt-hastings-adiabatic-quantum-computation-with-long-paths/ this blog by Matt Hastings says that SAT problems should take an exponentially, not doubly exponentially long time to solve using the adiabatic algorithm*.
- [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa05/projectreports/AdiabaticQC.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs191/fa05/projectreports/AdiabaticQC.pdf) (at the beginning of section 3) suggests solving NP-hard problems takes exponential time rather than doubly exponential time*.

*I am aware that we expect NP-hard problems to take an exponential amount of time to solve in the worst case. My question is different: why should expect the adiabatic algorithm to solve these problem in exponential time rather than doubly exponential time?

Comment: "I have often seen it stated that in the worst-case,$\Delta_{min} = 1/\exp(n)
$": Can you provide the references?

Comment: Have now added some.